# In a ring homomorphism we always have $f(1)=1$?

Tags: ring-theory, abstract-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [the image of $1$ by a  homomorphism between unitary rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78172/the-image-of-1-by-a-homomorphism-between-unitary-rings)

I'm studying the Atiyah's commutative algebra book and I realized that in the beginning of the book, the author says as one of the conditions to a map be a homomorphism is $f(1)=1$, I would like to know if I can left this condition behind, i. e., if $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ we can have $f(1)=1$.

Thanks

Comment: We can have $f(1)=1$, but we don't *must* have it.

Comment: As  YACP hints, your formulation of the question is probably not what you really mean: namely whether the axioms $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ imply  $f(1)=1$. The answer is "no" , as akkk and Jyrki  point out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. The constant 0 function (which has $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in R$) is not a ring homomorphism in the usual understanding, but satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$.

Answer (score 21):

The condition $f(1)=1$ is usually included in the definition of a ring homomorphism, when the (IMHO more common) convention that rings must have units is adopted. You want to rule out mappings like
$$
x\mapsto\pmatrix {x&0\cr0&0\cr}
$$
from being a homomorphism from, say, the reals to 2x2 real matrices.

Similar things might otherwise also happen between mappings between commutative rings (Atiyah's context). For example, the mapping $f:x\mapsto 3x$ from $\mathbb{Z}_6$ to itself does satisfy the conditions $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ and $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$. The latter condition follows from the congruence $3^2\equiv 3\pmod 6$.

More generally, if a commutative ring $R$ has an idempotent, i.e. an element $e$ that satisfies the relation $e^2=e$, then the mapping $x\mapsto xe$ satisfies both conditions
$f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ and $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ for all $a,b\in R$.

As you have seen there are several examples proving that the condition $f(1)=1$ does not follow from the other requirements of a ring homomorphism. Not even in the case, when $f(1)\neq0$.

---

Commenting a little bit as to why we (or at least Atiyah) want to rule out the mappings between rings that respect the binary operations, but don't map 1 to 1. In several parts of algebra emphasis is on modules over a ring. There it is essential that 1 acts as the identity mapping on the module. We also want to be able pull back the module structure as follows. If $M$ is an $S$-module and $f:R\rightarrow S$ is a ring homomorphism, we often want to turn $M$ into an $R$-module by the rule $r*m=f(r)m$. If we didn't know that $f(1_R)=1_S$, then we would need to worry, whether multiplication by $1_R$ is the identity mapping on $M$.

There may be several other reasons. The above is the first that occurred to me, because it really is everywhere in applications of modules. I guess it is possible to have a context, where this argument is not pressing, and then you can choose to work with a different definition.

Comment: Could you add a word on why we want to rule out such mappings?

Comment: @akkkk Universal algebra: "variety"/"quasivariety". Logic/model theory: "model homomorphism", "free model", "set of Horn clauses". OK, I somehow get the impression that I'm unable to convey this information with a single word. I probably have to write a complete answer with full details.

Comment: @Jyrik: Do you mean $3^{\mathbf{2}} \equiv 3 \mod 6$?

Comment: Correct, @tim6her. Thanks for spotting the typo.

Answer (score 3):

It could also be $f(1)=0$.

But looking at it from a logical point of view, a homomorphism would be a language and interpretation preserving function. In the language of unital rings we have two constants, $0,1$ and two operations $+,\cdot$. If we require that $f$ preserves the interpretation then $f(1_R)=1_S$ is an actual requirement.

Note that in such case the zero homomorphism is **not** a homomorphism of unital rings. You may wish to include it specifically or not. There is a good discussion on the topic here: [Does $\varphi(1)=1$ if $\varphi$ is a field homomorphism?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141770/does-varphi1-1-if-varphi-is-a-field-homomorphism)

Comment: I don't see the "otherwise". If $f$ is not surjective then $f(1)$ is only a unit for the subring $Im(f)$, this does not have to imply that it is a unit for the target.

Answer (score 2):

When discussing rings with unity (i.e. the category of unital rings, usually denoted **Ring**), authors usually require homomorphisms to preserve the unit element. When discussing rings that aren't necessarily unital (i.e. the category of "rngs", usually denoted **Rng**) authors usually don't require homomorphisms to preserve the unit element (should it exist).
Refer to [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_rings#Rings_without_identity).

Answer (score 1):

Let $ f: R \mapsto S$ 
And if $ f$ is not zero map, if it is zero map the condition is satisfied trivially.

So, assume $f(1) = a$ and $ a \neq 0$ 
Then $f(1) = f(1*1) = f(1)*f(1)$ if $f(1) \ne 0$ then $ f(1) = a^2 = a$ $ \Rightarrow $ and 
as the map is not trivial,$\exists s \in R $ such that $ f(s) \ne 0$  then $f(s) = f(1*s) = f(1)*f(s)$ so, $ f(s) = af(s) $ and again $  f(s*s) = f(as)*f(as) = a^2f(s)^2 $

So $ a^2 = a$ $\Rightarrow$ $(a-1)a = 0$ hence a is a zero divisor or 1.

If $f(s)$ is an unit then $a = 1$ or if the ring is a integral domain.

Comment: Your equality is true independently of whether $f(1)\neq 0$ or not and moreover does not answer the question: what is this "Hint" supposed to mean ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg, as the reader is doing Atiyah, I thought he should be able to do this proof himself, that's why I gave him a hint where to start.

Comment: To readers: my  comment above applied to a preceding version of the answer.

Comment: why $(a-1)a = 0$ implies $a$ is a zero divisor or 1? zero divisor, it's ok, but why 1? thank you for your answer.

Comment: If $a$ is not a zero divisor then $ a = 0$ or $ a-1 = 0$, but we assumed earlier that $ a \ne 0$ and hence $ a = 1$ and if $ f(s)$ is a unit in ring $S$ then you can simply cancel out $f(s)$ so, again $ a = 1$